# Count duplicate values in array

Tags: php, arrays

Counting values with the following code turns no results to my array. Would appreciate any help on what I did wrong thanks.

```php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");

$arr = array();
foreach($xml->url as $child)
{
    if (isset($child->loc)) {
        echo "true";
        $arr[] = $child->loc;
    } else {
        echo "error";
        echo  $child->loc; 
    }        
}
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
```

Comment: What this extra `?>` for?

Comment: My bad removed a content earlier.

Comment: count($arr) is also counts the no of entities of an array

Comment: Actually I want to count duplicates.

Comment: Can you show `var_dump($arr)` and `var_dump(array_count_values($arr))`?

Comment: Is it echoing "true" or "error"?

Comment: It's showing all proper values and echoing true, Just need to count them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast the item values properly, otherwise you would be storing SimpleXMLElement objects in your array:

```
$arr[] = (string)$child->loc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution formed after the answer of jack. Added this code to check for duplicates.

```
if(count($arr) != count(array_unique($arr))){
      echo "Duplicates";
   }
```

Comment: I guess that's debugging code, but if count($arr) doesn't equal count(array_unique($arr)) that means there _are_ duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

May be expecting like this

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($xml->url->loc[0]);
var_dump($xml->url->loc[1]);
var_dump($xml->url->loc[2]);

echo "</pre>";

$arr = array();

foreach($xml->url as $child)
{
    foreach($child as $tmp){    
        if (isset($tmp)) {
            echo "true";
            $arr[] = (String)$child->loc;
        } else {
            echo  "error<br/>";
            echo  $child->loc; 
        }    
    }    
}
print_r(array_count_values($arr));



<sites>
    <url>
        <loc>google.com</loc>
        <loc>google.com</loc>
        <loc>yahoo.com</loc>
    </url>
</sites>
```